# Mod Rewrite, ignore directory unless URL has a trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making an url shortener with a base 64 encoding for my urls. problem is I also have a bunch of folders inside my main directory. My directory looks something like this

```
/
  /css
    style.css
  /handlers
    handle_database.php
  index.php
  .htaccess
```

And this is the rewrite rule I use to capture the encoded urls

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{3,8})$ index.php?a=$1
```

And that works. my problem comes when my system generates an url that would be like this `http://exampleurlshortener.com/css`, in an ideal scenario the rewrite rule would capture the "css" and let my index.php handle the rest, problem is apache adds a trailing slash and it ends up getting inside the css directory.

So what I need is that
`http://exampleurlshortener/css` -> lets index.php handle the request
`http://exampleurlshortener/css/` -> access the actual directory

So far I've had no luck, because apache keeps adding the trailing slash

Comment: Use `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: No luck, any idea how to implement that?

Comment: did you try making the / optional in the rule? `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{3,8})/?$ index.php?a=$1`

Comment: @PanamaJack The `css/` directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off `DirectorySlash` to avoid `Apache` adding a trailing slash. It is also important to turn off `Indexes` option to avoid Apache presenting directory listing to users.

```
DirectorySlash off
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]{3,8})$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```